# Isapi Rewrite upgrade from 2 to 3 - query string not available?

Tags: seo, query-string, isapi-rewrite

A little late but I just upgraded from Isapi Rewrite version 2 to version 3.

I'm having problems with rules in the following style:

```
RewriteRule ^/seo-friendly/(\?(.*))? /test/index.cfm?page=home&$2
```

Here I want any extra query string parameters passed on to the rewritten URL.

This worked fine under IR2 but fails to pass the extra parameters in IR3. I have both the Regex tester .exe utilities from each version so I tried those.

If I enter **/seo-friendly/?hello=world**, IR2's regex tester says **$1: ?hello=world** and **$2: hello=world**
Which is perfect.

But IR3's says **$0: /seo-friendly/** and **$1** and **$2** are blank.

It looks like I can't access query string variables.

I found this flag mentioned in the docs:

> O (nOrmalize)
>
> Normalizes string before processing.
>   Normalization includes removing of an
>   URL-encoding, illegal characters, etc.
>   Also, IIS normalization of an URI
>   completely removes query string. So,
>   normalization should not be used if
>   query string is needed

But I haven't set this flag against my rules. Is there a global rule that I can set to stop this (apparent) normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ISAPI Rewrite works nearly the same as Apache’s mod_rewrite, you should just need to set the QSA flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/seo-friendly/$ /test/index.cfm?page=home [QSA]
```

Comment: I can't find any mention of it in their documentation but that flag works like a charm. Thanks a million!